# Get number of records in table during last day and last week with single query in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have table with timestamp in one column (MySQL 5.5). Is it possible to get number of records during last 1 day (last 86400 seconds) and number of records during last week (last 604800 seconds) in single query?

I know how to do it with 2 queries, but it would be nice to know if there is some neat solution to this.

```
timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: Erm yeah. You want two records (union query), or one a self join?

Comment: Don't know... I want result as array of answers, something like this: ['1 days' => 41, '7 days' => 302] (PHP array syntax)

Comment: Also as short as possible, but still easy to read/understand what query is about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and Dirty is just a Union then.

```
Select '1 Days', Count(*) as NumberOf from sometable 
Where `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
union
Select '7 Days', Count(*) as from sometable 
Where `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Gets painful and perhaps expensive if you have a lot of ranges though. f So you might want to look at DateDiff to calculate the interval once and then count that.

Comment: Oh neat. I was not aware I can easily combine results of two unrelated queries. Also really easy to understand what it does... Thank you